# Shell Script Invocation Error IOS after Ejecting From React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I ejected from expo project and I keep error in the IOS build. When I run npm run ios. The error I get is

> The following build commands failed:
>           PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Users/mypc/Documents/Apps/VodafoneApp/ios/build/MyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
>   (1 failure)

Also, I have an error on third-party-install, I have tried almost all the solutions I can get. Cleared rncache folder but yet no progress.

> /Users/my/Documents/Apps/myapp/ios/build/MyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh:
>   line 3: exec: /Users/mypc/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh:
>   cannot execute: No such file or directory